# Functional Analysis, looks like Riesz

Tags: functional-analysis

This is a problem from my Functional Analysis class.

Let $U,V$ be subspaces of a Hilbert spaces. $U$ is finite dimensional and $\dim (U)<\dim(V)$. Show that there is a $v\in V$ such that $\|v\|=1$ and $\langle u,v\rangle=0$ for all $u\in U$.

Answer (score 5):

Take a $v\in V$, $v\not\in U$, and consider the projection $u_0$ of $v$ onto $U$. Then $v^\bot=v-u_0$ is orthogonal to $U$. Normalize $v^\bot$.

Comment: Are you sure $v^{\perp}\in V$?